# Django AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view' in urls.py

Tags: python, django

Django AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view' in urls.py

urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from . import views, converter

register_converter(converter.HexConverter, 'hex')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.QuestionView.as_view()),
    path('ask/', views.Ask.as_view()),
    path('<hex:pk>/', views.QuestionCurrent.as_view(), name='question_current'),
]
```

views.py file

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import QuestionForm
from .models import *

def QuestionView(request):
    ''' List of Questions '''
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'f/index.html', {'question_list': questions})

def QuestionCurrent(request, pk):
    ''' Current Question '''
    question = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'f/current.html', {'question': question})

class Ask(CreateView):
    template_name = 'f/ask.html'
    form_class = QuestionForm
    success_url = '/f/ask/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        content = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return content
```

forms.py file

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('author', 'title', 'body')
```

some more details, some more details, some more details.

Comment: It means `QuestionView`, `Ask`, or `QuestionCurrent` are *not* class-based views. If these are functions, then you can't use `.as_view()`.

Comment: Please, show your views code

Answer (score 0):

It means `QuestionView`, `Ask`, or `QuestionCurrent` are *not* class-based views. If these are functions, then you can't use [**`.as_view()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view).

The `.as_view()` function is used to turn the class of class-based view into a function that will handle the requests. In case the `QuestionView`, `Ask` and/or `QuestionCurrent` views are thus functions, you should drop the `.as_view()` of the *corresponding* views:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.QuestionView),
    path('ask/', views.Ask.as_view()),
    path('<hex:pk>/', views.QuestionCurrent, name='question_current'),
]
```

As you can see in the views, the `QuestionView` and the `Ask` are *functions*:

```
def QuestionView(request):
    ''' List of Questions '''
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'f/index.html', {'question_list': questions})

def QuestionCurrent(request, pk):
    ''' Current Question '''
    question = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'f/current.html', {'question': question})
```

Only `Ask` is a *class-based* view.

Furthermore such functions are usually written in `snake_case`, not in `PerlCase`.

Comment: so how can i fix it?

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon: as specified, you drop the `.as_view()` for the view *functions*, so views that are not classes, but functions, like `def QuestionView(..) ...`.

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon: but you can not simply copy without context. If in that book the views are implemented differently, then it will of course not work. If for example the book has a `class QuestionView(ListView):` then it is a class-based view. If you on the other hand define it as `def QuestionView(request):...`, then the two don't match. You can not copy some part of the code verbatim and expect it to work.

Comment: in that book, the author is using classes not functions in his views file and is not getting errors

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon: exactly. And the error message says, that you are using (at least one) function. Since the error message is **function** object has no attribute `.as_view()`.

Comment: @someseeapeniseeaharpoon: based on the edit, as you can see the `Ask` and the `QuestionView` started with `def`, so these are functions, and you can not use `.as_view()` on these.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t import Ask class view in the url.py!

I think you forgot to do this:
From.views import Ask

also QuestionView was created using function View!
You can’t call it using as_view().

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the write "class" instead of "def" in the below two functions.
Also import the views from rest_framework.

```
def QuestionView(request):
    ''' List of Questions '''
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'f/index.html', {'question_list': questions})

def QuestionCurrent(request, pk):
    ''' Current Question '''
    question = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'f/current.html', {'question': question})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).